# How to write an exception handler in Linux kernel module

Tags: linux, driver, kernel-module, exceptionhandler

I am writing a Linux driver, which will interact with user programs. This driver will receive some parameters from user code. However, some exceptions may occur in the kernel module. For example, there is an invalid pointer in these parameters, and the page fault will occur. Then the user program will be killed.

Assume that there is no way to check whether these parameters are valid at the software level, the only thing I can do is to use hareware signals. I want to know how to create a custom exception handler in Linux kernel module (like `sigaction()` API in user mode in libc). Thanks!

Comment: Linux kernel modules don't use signals or C++ exceptions. Typically they use `if` and error return values (e.g. EINVAL).

Comment: Use `access_ok`, `if` and `__copy_from_user`.

Comment: Thanks. I've discovered that I can exploit Linux exception table to register some custom exception handlers, which may also be the mechanism with `access_ok`.